# Primefaces p:datatable how can we make a bottom scrollbar shown in a datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

My codes is like this...but no scrollbar shown in bottom.
how can we make a bottom scrollbar shown in a datatable?

```
<p:dataTable scrollHeight="250"  id="data" var="item" value="#{saleOrderDetailViewModel.items}" 
                resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" scrollable="true" rowIndexVar="rowInfo" 
                emptyMessage="#{pmtsCommonUtilViewModel.datatableEmptyMessage}"  
                paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" rows="#{pmtsCommonUtilViewModel.rowsPerPage}"  
                rowsPerPageTemplate="#{pmtsCommonUtilViewModel.rowsPerPageTemplate}"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">

                    <p:column id="order_no" rendered="true" headerText="销售单编号" style="width:130px"> 
                        #{item.orderNo} 
                    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Try to specify `scrollWidth`.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for others may know the solution faster.(No need to look at comments above.)

Answer (score 0):

Specify `scrollWidth` when you want bottom scrollbar shown.

Like this:

```
<p:dataTable scrollWidth="250" scrollHeight="250" id="data" var="item" value="#{saleOrderDetailViewModel.items}" 
            resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" scrollable="true" rowIndexVar="rowInfo" 
            emptyMessage="#{pmtsCommonUtilViewModel.datatableEmptyMessage}"  
            paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" rows="#{pmtsCommonUtilViewModel.rowsPerPage}"  
            rowsPerPageTemplate="#{pmtsCommonUtilViewModel.rowsPerPageTemplate}"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">

                <p:column id="order_no" rendered="true" headerText="销售单编号" style="width:130px"> 
                    #{item.orderNo} 
                </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```